# Why does it says "welcome back -user- click here to 'refresh page'"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-bydesign

After logging into one Stack Exchange site, when I visit another SE site,
it says to me, welcome back - user - click here to refresh - web page.

Isn't it possible to refresh the page using code & without the user's interaction?

Comment: See also Kevin Montrose's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122300/131713).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because the auto-login process happens asynchronously. In other words, you may already be reading stuff, have already scrolled down, started typing, or whatnot, when the login process is completed. Automatically refreshing would be annoying in this case.

In one case, though, this *will* happen automatically (proving that it's not a technical problem): When you're on the login page, we take it as granted that you want to go back to whereever you clicked "log in" (e.g. on the chat site), so it's safe to automatically redirect you back.

Comment: Am I right to assume you considered loading the top bar (Inbox, user name, reputation, links) instead of showing that banner? (Apart from the development effort, I can also imagine that such would cause more confusion as the remaining contents of the page would not reflect favorite and ignored tags then.)

Comment: @Arjan Yeah, there's tons and tons page content that changes when you log in. Requiring a single F5 or click (only happening once for a session anyway) to make sure that the complete page fits the login that's displayed in the top bar is just the best way to go. Changing the whole page content unobtrusively is just close to impossible (think: deleted answers suddenly appearing, the links under the post changing, comment controls changing, vote arrows changing, etc.).

Comment: (Ah, I didn't even think about pages other than the home page!)

Comment: why not do the refresh automatically if the user hasn't scrolled yet?

Comment: This is pretty annoying to see across 5 or 6 stack exchange websites one after the other - I'd prefer to see uncustomised content or asynchronously load the user information top bar rather than this banner.

Answer (score 8):

This is a very valid question.

It's certainly possible to refresh the affected parts of the page automatically through ajax; asking the user to refresh themselves the page feels hacky..

Comment: the user settings affect a large part of the page; you're hand-waving that away as trivial.

Comment: @Jeff, Rebecca is saying the same thing below. Could you expand on that or link to a blog post of yours explaining it?

Comment: @Jeff, I really don't see it (see my edit below, if you please)

Comment: @JeffAtwood Can't we have a few workarounds to ease the pain?

Such as:

On question pages when the user tries to do something that requires logging in, automatically refresh and perform the action they were trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

It is a new feature, if you are already logged into one SE site, and you visit another SE site that you *already have an account for*, it will **automatically** log you in.

> A user having logged into any SE-site will be automatically logged into every other SE-site on which they have an account
>
> Source: [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work)

Comment: Then why does it says - click here to refresh page ?

Comment: @sagar: because it takes a sec or two to see you there and log you in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'click here' isn't needed. There is no need at all to show a notification bar. If SE is able to determine that the user is registered, they could 'just' put the username at the right spot at the top of the page.

The 'only' reason to refresh the page is the added functionality at the top of the page (StackExchange area with notifications, user area with hover) that nobody would miss really.

**Edit**
Before clicking 'click here'.
[image: Logon]

After clicking...
[image: After logon]

The only difference I see is the 'Welcome' box on the right that was replaced by the 'Favorite Tag' and 'Ignored Tag' textbox.

Comment: Being logged in means a lot more than *just* a name shown at the top of the page.  There are privileges that come with being logged in and having reputation, and that affects a significant portion of the page.

Comment: Arriving at Q&A? I only see a bunch of questions.

Comment: Maybe the user has favorite/ignored tags that affect the display of those questions.  Maybe the user has notifications they are supposed to get.  Maybe the user went directly to a question page and thus a significant portion of the page is affected.  Maybe the user went directly to their profile and needs their authenticated view of their profile.  Etc...

Comment: Now that many details are loaded dynamically (see [Real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)), it indeed seems that the user details could be added this way too. But I'm not sure if it's worth the effort, given the exceptions that @Rebecca mentioned, and also her note about about how some users might expect some questions to be removed from their home page. So, a message about the refresh doesn't look too bad to me either.