# Global login or logout to SE sites

Tags: feature-request, login, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add “network wide logout” functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality)

Currently, there is no easy way to globally log in or out of *all* SE sites automatically. True, on JavaScript-supported browsers, you are logged in when you view the page, but there should be a feature that skips this step. Likewise, for logging *out*, there should be an option to log out of *all* SE sites, rather than logging out of each site one by one.

My model for globally logging in and out is how [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) is currently being employed on the Wikimedia sites (such as Wikipedia, Wiktionary, Wikinews, etc.). Of course, there are some specific wikis where global login is purposely disabled (for security purposes), but for the most part, global login *works*.

Comment: @Developer Art How about automated login to all of your favorite sites?

Comment: And the reason why the refresh is required: [Why is there a “click here to refresh the page” bit to login to SE sites? (But not on careers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81472/why-is-there-a-click-here-to-refresh-the-page-bit-to-login-to-se-sites-but-no/81475#81475) and [Why does it says welcome back -user- click here to “refresh page”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73191/why-does-it-says-welcome-back-user-click-here-to-refresh-page/73194#73194).