# Why do I have to refresh to log in?

Tags: feature-request, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does it says “welcome back -user- click here to 'refresh page'”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73191/why-does-it-says-welcome-back-user-click-here-to-refresh-page)
>   [Why does Stack Exchange ask for a reload on successful automatic login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122295/why-does-stackexchange-ask-for-a-reload-on-successful-automatic-login)

I occasionally see this message:

[image]

I don't know why I need to see this. I don't like having this huge distracting message just to tell me I'm logged in.

Shouldn't it either

- log me in before the server delivers the page, or, if that's not technically feasible
- log me in asynchronously instead of showing the banner?

Comment: The proposed duplicate has a link here as well but, just in case, [this answer is useful too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122300/165455).