# Why does auto-login sometimes auto-refresh and sometimes not?

Tags: support, bug, redirection, auto-login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does it says “welcome back -user- click here to 'refresh page'”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73191/why-does-it-says-welcome-back-user-click-here-to-refresh-page)

Stack Exchange's autologin seems to have inconsistent behavior as to

1. whether it activates at all, and
2. whether the page auto-refreshes after activating.

[1 [has been answered in detail]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64274/146243), but what about 2?

After auto-login, the banner saying you have been logged in automatically appears. But then:

- Sometimes the banner continues, "You are being redirected"; the page refreshes; and I am logged in automatically.
- Sometimes the banner continues, "Click here to refresh"; then I have to refresh the page (or click there) before I am logged in.

Is this a bug, or is there a reason behind the seemingly inconsistent behavior here?

Comment: As I said in my answer to that other question, you'll get an auto-redirect on the login page, and there only.