# Don't tell me to log in to vote if I've already been auto-logged in

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, auto-login

OK, we've all seen the "*Welcome back [USERNAME], you've been logged in. Click here to refresh the page.*" auto-login notification bar, and I understand [why it works the way it does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73191/why-does-it-says-welcome-back-user-click-here-to-refresh-page).  And having the up- and downvote buttons work as [anonymous user feedback for non-logged-in users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/161595#161595) is also a nice touch.  But the way these two features interact, when I go to a post on a site I'm not currently logged in on (e.g. via the "hot questions" list) and try to vote on it, is kind of silly:

[image: Screenshot of auto-login bar and anonymous user feedback notice together]

The page already knows I've been logged in, it even knows who I am (since it can show my username in the notification bar).  Surely the script that handles the vote buttons could be made smart enough to check for that and just let me vote normally without having to reload the page?

Comment: I guess the technical complication is not to morph a anonymous page into a personalized page on the client, but to create the loged-in sessioin state on the server in an unusual context, and keep it consistent. I think any implementation of web logins just expect loading a new page, naturally.

Comment: When you click on the vote button as an anonymous user, it POSTS to `http://site.stackexchange.com/posts/popup/anon-vote/postID?voteTypeId=n`. Maybe that needs to change so it returns nothing (HTTP 204) and the browser would instead POST to `http://site.stackexchange.com/posts/postID/vote/n` if you're logged in?

Comment: @Uni this might not be relevant anymore. Ilmari can you please try to reproduce this? I suspect that with the recent login changes, there is no such banner anymore.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, but the login popup is still the same

Comment: @Uni  right, but the point of this feature request is that it's misleading when you see the "Welcome back" banner on top. Without this banner, it is not relevant.