# Moving back and forth between communities

Tags: feature-request

Often when looking at questions in a community that I have an account in (say, stackoverflow), I'll notice an interesting question from another community in the sidebar (say physics.stackexchange.com). As I do not have an account here, I am now 'logged out' from the stackoverflow family of websites and can't use the drop-down menu in the top-left to get back to one of my subscribed sites. This seems reasonable, as physics.stackexchange.com doesn't 'know' that I have an account on any of the other stackexchange sites.

However, I also can't click back to stackexchange.com, from where I WOULD be able to use the drop-down to get back to 'known territory'. I would much appreciate it if there was an easy way to get back to your subscribed sites, without first creating an account on the newly visited page or having to type the address in my address bar.

Comment: The new login system that is currently under development may get this request fulfilled as a byproduct.

Comment: The "more stack exchange communities" in the site switcher is a direct link to http://stackexchange.com/sites so you can use it. Only two clicks away. :-)

Comment: Related, almost a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210961/keeping-the-top-bar-logged-in

Comment: BTW, for this particular use case, what's wrong with the browser "back" button?