# refresh for me instead of telling me to click here

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, auto-login

Instead of telling me to *Click here* to refresh the page, please just do it automatically for me. Preferably by just saying logging you in as pictured below, so the user knows they are about to have the page refreshed.

[image]

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73194/244519), the reason we don't already have this feature is because if you open a link to a post, it would supposedly be annoying to have the page refresh while you already started reading the post. However, I don't find this to be the case, since the banner itself is kind of annoying, especially when it just sits there until you click on it or click to go to another page on that site. Also, if you go to an answer link, it blocks the top part of the answer as shown below. So that seems to be a bug.

[image]

So please just implement this to save users clicks and mouse movements. It would be much more user friendly in my opinion, especially for users who are members of many SE sites.

Comment: No automatic refreshes - what if you type some answer? refresh will drop all that stuff.

Comment: The refresh will happen within 1 to 5 seconds, doubt you'd have much of an answer written up in that time frame.

Comment: @cVplZ, and it's going to happen later? Due to network issue?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

For one, as mentioned in the other post, it can be annoying to have it refresh while you're in the middle of reading a post. kitty commented here that if you started an answer, refresh would lose it. It's certainly possible to have started writing an answer, if your network is slow and doesn't register that you're logged on right away.

Once the banner shows up, you're already logged in, and can vote, comment, answer, etc. It's just that the UI hasn't changed to reflect that.

And as for saving clicks and mouse movement... <kbd>f5</kbd>.

Comment: From what I understand, the system automatically saves your last draft post, so it shouldn't be lost in a refresh.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't always work. I've lost posts because they weren't saved properly.