# Improving the Global Network Auto-Login experience

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, login, user-experience

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/
[How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/)

Something about having to deal with this feels really clunky. Am I the only one who feels this way? Is there anything that can be done to improve this user experience?

[image: auto login]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/global-auth-in-action.png))</sub>

Said another way, if I had to deal with this going from gmail to google docs to google reader, it would annoy me to no end. Especially as stackexchange grows and the network becomes a destination for interesting content, I don't really want to confront this boundary every time I go from site to site.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly bothers you about it?

Answer (score 2):

The page doesn't refresh automatically out of courtesy (it will though if you are on the /login page).

The only part, however, that really feels clunky is when you're logged in on one of the sites but you aren't on chat.SE and "your login data is too old", at which point you have to login *somewhere* ("let's try SU, am I logged in there?)...

There *is* a ghetto login system that lets you login *by virtue of being logged in* instead of logging in because you logged in recently to some site, but it's quite hidden (I don't even know how to get there via links only).

Answer (score 0):

> Something about having to deal with this feels really clunky. Am I the only one who feels this way?

I'm not sure what it is that feels "clunky". The system works well as far as I am concerned...

> Especially as stackexchange grows and the network becomes a destination for interesting content, I don't really want to confront this boundary every time I go from site to site

You should only see that message *once per site* unless you're logging out. After that, you're logged in to each site and will remain logged in. Are you seeing that message every time you switch sites? If so then something is not working correctly for you.