# How does Stack Overflow recognize my account, though I always delete cookies, history, etc?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, openid

Stack Overflow is the only site, which I access and get greetings: `"Welcome %username%"`.

I didn't access OpenID account before visiting Stack Overflow and do not store any cookies, history or whatever - it is all wiped out after closing the browser (Opera btw). How is done, actually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it is all wiped out after closing the browser (Opera btw)

Not really, see following screen shot on opera setting.

[image]

There is only "**new** cookies delete" option when exiting opera (only new, old cookies will remain)

Try with "Delete Private Data..." option, and make sure you selected following

[image]

and try again opening stackoverflow.com after that.

Comment: That helped, thanks:). Nevertheless, how did Stackoverflow cookies were stored, if new ones always supposed to be deleted? Those privacy settings I use from the very beginning.

Comment: @87element, 1) stackoverflow have own cookie other than openid's cookie, and 2) can automatically sync logins within various stackoverflow family sites. I am not sure what is your real issue though, but it looks like you have some cookies remain in your browser.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue in Safari, caused by the Stack Exchange global network auto-login using [HTML5 local storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-localstorage). Safari does not show that, but also does not allow me to delete it.

Browsing to [stackauth.com](http://stackauth.com/) and pasting the following into the location bar, shows it:

```
javascript:alert(localStorage.getItem('GlobalLogin'));
```

In Google Chrome "Delete cookies and other site data" also clears local storage. In Firefox, it's deleted whenever cookies are deleted. In Safari (on a Mac): no luck, other than deleting directly from the file system (`~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage` on my Mac, which incidentially shows all domains that use local storage one has ever visited, <s>including those not using local storage at all,</s> even when using private browsing).

(See also [How to clear all HTML5 local storage from Safari?](https://superuser.com/questions/236558/how-to-clear-all-html5-local-storage-from-safari) on Super User, [Global Network Auto-Login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) on the blog, and Kevin's detailed explanation in [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274) here on Meta.)

Answer (score 1):

You are a registered user - https://stackoverflow.com/users/626385/87element - so you must have an OpenID account (or equivalent) that you used when you first logged in.