# How am I being logged in automatically even if I clear all my Chrome data from "the beginning of time"?

Tags: support, login, auto-login

I cleared all my browser data and visited http://stackoverflow.com and it logged me back in. How?

This happens on Chrome on OS X and Windows 7.

Surely the security concerns outweigh the benefits to the user. What if a family member or friend wants to use my machine? I wouldn't want them logged in as me.

**Update**

My mistake, I should have said *data* — all those checkboxes clicked/checked. I completely cleared everything, yet it still logs me back in.

**Update 2**

Here's a video to prove it:
[flickr.com/photos/therobyouknow/7749178118/in/photostream](http://flickr.com/photos/therobyouknow/7749178118/in/photostream)

Comment: You cleared just your history? That doesn't achieve a whole lot.

Comment: Related: [With cookies deactivated, how does stackoverflow log me in automaticly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106559/with-cookies-deactivated-how-does-stackoverflow-log-me-in-automaticly), [How can Stack Overflow automatically login after resetting Safari?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110291/how-can-stack-overflow-automatically-login-after-resetting-safari), [How does Stack Overflow recognize my account, though I always delete cookies, history, etc?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/how-does-stack-overflow-recognize-my-account-though-i-always)

Comment: No actually, I cleared EVERYTHING, from the beginning of time... (sorry *history* was not the correct word for it)

Comment: If you are sure you did, then from my understanding SO simply can't log you in automatically. And using Chrome myself I have certainly never seen this behavior. You are sure you did not click the image/link for your particular OpenID provider?

Comment: There you go, proof enough: http://www.flickr.com/photos/therobyouknow/7749178118/in/photostream

Comment: Clear all data. Close your browser. Not just the tab (All instances if you have more than one running). Start it again. Same problem?

Comment: Yes, same problem, did a `ps -ef | grep chrome` in Terminal to ensure no Chrome instances running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We use local storage to store important information about your login.  I do see somebody else with a report of an issue with clearing local storage in the latest version of chrome 21:  https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-html5/ize_mpI3e8w%5B1-25%5D

Confirmed - chrome v20 will clear local storage when you clear all browsing data - chrome v21.0.1180.75 will not.

Comment: +1 "chrome v21.0.1180.75 will not." is that a bug or a feature? To me that sounds like a bug in Chrome then. Security concern. "local storage" can be classified as "browsing data".

Comment: @therobyouknow You can manually clear the local storage by opening the developer tools, and pasting `localStorage.clear();` in the console. Another option is to open the dev tools, open the Resources panel -> Local storage, and right-click on the entries to choose "Delete".

Comment: Alternatively, in Settings->Advance Settings, click Content Settings (this button is next to Clear browsing data, then click All Cookies and site data... then a list is displayed - local storage item 'stackauth' corroborates with @Geoff Dalgas's point. Click 'remove all' to remove all of the list. Click Clear browsing data and that will do the trick - will solve my problem - this solution in the link that Geoff mentioned. I still think it's a bug because 'clear browsing data' includes 'clear cookies and *other site* and plug-in *data* and one would therefore expect this to clear *everything*.

Comment: Accepting this answer with the comments as it explains why -- and also provides a link to solve the problem.

Comment: +1 RobW for your alternative solution - this is a nice intro to the developer tools for me :)

Answer (score 2):

As Bart points out, browser history doesn't have anything to do with OpenID login that Stack Exchange uses. You'll need to clear your cookies and/or local storage data. In Chrome, that's one more checkbox you'll need to tick:

> [image]

Comment: All of them were checked. I'll try it again now... see you in a few secs...

Comment: ...I'm back. Yes it auto-logged me in. Every single checkbox ticked. From. The. Beginning. Of. Time. ...too!