# Logout not stable

Tags: support, logout

After I logout properly from Stackoverflow account, when I login again without asking for credentials, it logs in automatically. How can I avoid this?
I am using Google Chrome Browser.

Comment: You probably chose "Remember me" for the OpenID provider - likely Google.

Comment: I never chose  "Remember me" and I don't like it. May be there is problem with my browser settings.

Comment: Hmm.. when you go to gmail (assuming you're using Google account) do you also login automatically?

Comment: Not at all my dear. I tried with other browsers and it's normal.

Comment: You can open Chrome in [Incognito Mode](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464) this way next time you open it, all credentials will surely be cleared.

Comment: Oh no! Now it happens to other browsers also. Now I'm using Firefox. I don't understand what is going on...

Comment: Brrrr... I'm tired of this. I don't even care anymore. Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: Related: [When does a login happen automatically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/when-does-a-login-happen-automatically) Logging out from a site 1) stops auto-logging in to any other site one was not logged in to yet (the HTML5 Local Storage is wiped), and 2) keeps one from being auto-logged in to that very first site even after explicitly logging in to another site, until one restarts the browser (the "gauthed" cookie is wiped), or until one explicitly clicks "log in".

Comment: Also note that Chrome 21 has a bug that does not clear the local storage [when manually trying to do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142886/why-does-so-log-me-in-even-if-i-clear-all-my-chrome-data-from-the-beginning-of/142912#142912).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem sometimes (and, like you, I never chose "Remember me"). But if you clean your browser history it will avoid it. I believe it's a cookie issue.

Comment: You are right. It's because of those tasty crunchy Cookies :)

Comment: I've found that clearing cookies is insufficient in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to clearing cache is logging out, and then logging into a different stack exchange site as the user you really want to login as. Then on the original stack exchange site that you incorrectly logged into the first time, you can login in again and this time you will be logged in as the correct user.