# Add "network wide logout" functionality

Tags: feature-request, logout

Is a "log out from every SE site in the network" button technically feasible?

With so many SE sites popping up, it would be a very useful feature.

**Edit**: has this been implemented now, as @Ben suggests in his comment? I've lost track.

Comment: +1 from me, although given how unreliable the Windows Live logout used to be across multiple sites (As an example of another SSO implementation - I haven't used it in a long time so don't know if it's improved!), I suspect that using your browsers "Delete Cookies" tools may well be less painful! =)

Comment: Also, as Safari on a Mac [has no means to clear HTML5 Local Storage](http://superuser.com/questions/236558/how-to-clear-all-html5-local-storage-from-safari), it would be the only way to achieve this in that browser, other than manually deleting files from the file system...

Comment: @rob delete cookies won't work; cookies != html5 local storage

Comment: @Jeff, on a Mac in Google Chrome "Delete cookies and other site data" *does* clear local storage as well. In Firefox, it's deleted whenever cookies are deleted. Just not so much in Safari.

Comment: @Jeff - I wasn't aware that SE uses html5 local storage, I just assumed cookies (Yes, I know, my bad!). Substitute "Clear persisted data" for "Delete Cookies" for an implementation agnostic version of my comment =)

Comment: @Rob, please find a button labelled "Clear persisted data" in my Safari on a Mac ;-) (Well, actually, I use Chrome most times, so no issue for me. It's more about Safari users being oblivious about what is stored on their disk, even after clicking every available button that might clear it. I dislike that a lot.)

Comment: @rob very few browsers clear HTML5 storage in that manner, though I haven't checked FF4 and IE9 recently.

Comment: @Rob, [Global Network Auto-Login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) and [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274) are a nice read.

Comment: @Jeff, in Chrome on a Mac, I have no option to *only* delete cookies. It's Delete cookies [and other site data](http://i.imgur.com/Ul6UF.png), or nothing.

Comment: So if I clear all browsing data in, say, Chrome 14 (PC or Mac), am I logging myself out of all SE sites or leaving them logged in if I forgot to actually click the logout link?

Comment: See also: "[Improve SE OpenID logout security and user experience on shared or public machines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119399/135887)", to which this feature request would be a solution.

Comment: where is the converse? network wide login would be quite useful for me

Comment: I think this is what happens now...

Comment: @BenBrocka it clears the globalauth local storage data, and it logs you out of the site you're presently on. It does not, however, log you out of _all_ sites. So if I'm logged into Superuser.com and Stackoverflow.com, and I initiate a logout on SU, I won't be auto-logged-in to Serverfault.com if I go over there, but I'm still logged in on SO.

Comment: @nhinkle hm, that's not what I get at all. In fact it seems to log me out on all devices on all sites, or it did the last time I did it. Which is not something I'd like to test again...

Comment: @BenBrocka I did it just the other day, and the behavior above is what I experienced. YMMV though - Stack Exchange has never been very good at log-outs.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Same. Only logs out of the one site and its meta and chat (same for logging out of `stackexchange.com`).

Comment: @Jarrod no it's not completed, and if it is it's a well kept secret how to use it.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, please implement this

I often like to check SE sites while not at home, and I don't like leaving myself logged in on someone else's computer. Currently I have to go to each site individually and log out. If I miss any site, then they get logged in as me if they go to any SE site afterwards.

As for the current suggestion of clearing cookies/temp data, it doesn't seem right to clear someone else's cookies and temp data, so its not a solution I ever use.

Comment: One solution is to use incognito mode when logging in. This should clear out the cookies etc. automatically. In addition it won't mess with their browsing history.

Comment: @ChrisF Is that available in all the major browsers?

Comment: It's certainly available in Chrome (incognito mode), IE9 (InPrivate browsing) and Firefox (Private mode). It's also available in Opera (Private mode) and Safari (Private browsing)

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks :) I was aware that Chrome had something like that and suspected FF did, but didn't know IE had that feature too, and IE is usually what's on other people's computers.

Comment: @ChrisF: Incognito is good... assuming you think about it in advance. It helps nothing if already logged in. I wonder on how many computers and on how many sites I'm currently logged in.