# Logout from Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, logout, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add “network wide logout” functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality)

How to logout from all Stack Exchange sites at once?

Right now, I am signing out individually from each Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do this at the moment. Here is [an existing request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality) for it to be added.