# SO's auth system

Tags: discussion, meta, authentication

The open id style authentication systems employed across the exchange sites are a marvel of concise usability. Would it be rude to emulate them for my own group of sites? After all, imitation is the sincerest form of flattery. I don't suppose there's any technical descriptions of the workings available?

Clearly a meta-question but I'm new to meta. If this question belongs elsewhere, please say so.

Comment: I knew there was someone out there who loved it!  We've finally found you :)

Comment: May I take that as a yes? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenID isn't really a Stack Exchange thing, but you can see [their website](http://openid.net/) for more details about how that works. (And yes, you can use it for your own sites).

Comment: And just to be sure: the Global Network Auto-Login is not related to that, but is covered [in the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) and in more detail [here on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274).

Comment: I understand that there are multiple open-id style protocols from various providers and that they're publicly accessible. My question regards the specifics of SE's endpoints and the site's authentication system as a whole.

Comment: @noodl There is one OpenID protocol that the various providers have agreed to use... SE doesn't do anything different from other OpenID consumers. You can see [their "Getting Started" page](http://openid.net/add-openid/add-getting-started/) which shows you how to start using it.

Comment: Thanks @Arjan, if I could mark your comment as the answer I would. That's just what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, @noodl, it's not what you asked for... So, waiwai933's answer is the one!