# Where does StackOverflow store login information on my computer?

Tags: discussion, cookies, login, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work)

I've noticed that, even after I delete all cookies, Firefox Cache, Flash cache, etc. StackOverflow still knows who I am and automatically logs me in. It's a nice feature but if StackOverflow can do it, so can others. Where does StackOverflow store my login information on my computer on Firefox 3.6 / Windows 7?

Comment: I think the answer is HTML5 local storage. I don't know how it works on non-HTML5 browsers, though.

Comment: Odd that clearing the cookies in Firefox didn't work for you; in my earlier tests that worked fine in Firefox and Chrome, just [not in Safari](http://superuser.com/questions/236558/how-to-clear-all-html5-local-storage-from-safari). Or did you only delete specific cookies?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you are logged in with Google or Facebook or another service which is coupled to your Stackoverflow account?