# No auto login for some SEs

Tags: discussion, login

I'm assuming the fact there's no automatic login for [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com), etc. is by design.

But why?

---

By "automatic login" I mean when a banner slides down saying something like "You've been logged in. Click here to refresh"

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic login"?

Comment: @Cody probably the [Global Network Auto-Login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/)?

Answer (score 5):

It should work on all (non-meta) sites; however, it will only try once (otherwise the check would run *everytime* a not-logged in user visits *any* page). So if you visit english.se, then log in to diy.se, then go back to english.se, it won't try to auto-login again.

The login page is an exception -- it will always try there. Does it work on [the english.se login page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/login)?

Comment: Ok I understand now. I'm assuming by "try" you mean look for a session variable/cookie/etc? I opened another browser there and first I tried "if you visit english.se, then log in to diy.se, then go back to english.se, it won't try to auto-login again." and it didn't auto-login like you said. But then I restarted the browser, logged into webmasters.se, then went to english.se and it didn't log me then either. (Browser used: Firefox. Newest version)

Comment: @AdamLynch: Yes, that's what I meant by "trying"; the session lookup requires two additional HTTP requests. If you're intersted, [Kevin has explained the process in some detail](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274).