# Can we have a global auto-login button somewhere?

Tags: support, auto-login

**Edit:** I've been having problems with the global auto-login since it was released. For some reason, my user (I've even switched to SOID) will not always trigger the auto-login. But sometimes it does...

When things go wrong, I experience the following: 1. Logged in at one site. 2. Visit second site - no auto-login. 3. Click [login], no auto-login 4. Enter SOID/Password.

See comments for more info. **Close Edit.**

Just like [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality), but the opposite, a global login button to log into each site without having to give the OpenID/password for each site.

Or, maybe, a login button next to each user site at the 'network profile' page (where I'm logged out, for some reason :-( )

The reason I'm asking is because I have a problem with the auto-login. Similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91916/no-auto-login-for-some-ses) and when I go to the [login] page, it won't get my credentials. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, Firefox 12. It appears to work on Ubuntu 12.04. I've been having these problems with the global auto-login since day one (other SO, other browser).

Comment: I'm trying to get into UX.SE through auto-login. Doesn't work. I've deleted UX from the browser history.... Now I can't get onto Cooking.SE!

Comment: I cleared your sessions on UX, try and log in again?

Comment: @BenBrocka, Nothing, nada, nilch

Comment: I could login the hard way, of course, if you want

Comment: Sounds like a workaround for some problem you're having? Why not look for a solution to that problem instead? (See also [What else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208))

Comment: @Arjan, just ran [this check](http://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) and 'Success'. Seems like I have everything that's needed (and have had ever since day one).

Comment: Have you logged out (log out is universal now) and then tried to log back in? Or (first) tried to log in using a different machine?

Comment: @BenBrocka, same thing. Logged out, logged in (at MSO), logged in at Askubuntu, not at cooking or UX.

Comment: Weird, by logging in you should be auto-logged in across the SE network, though JS has to do it's thing. Might want to make this a [support] Q btw

Comment: @Arjan, this morning I closed the browser, opened it again and the auto-login was working correctly :-)

Comment: @BenBrocka, please read the comment above this one. I'll delete this question in a short while.

Comment: Ok, odd! Nice to know that all sites have this test link; just as you wrote "I ran this check" I figured you checked if the *listed* requirements were met, and added the chat test link to the FAQ. Next, coming back here to tell you, I saw you actually linked "this".

Comment: @Arjan, ;-) In the mean while, I've been thinking that my original feature request isn't that bad, it prevents the 'welcome back' banner (a minor annoyance) but more importantly, you can force the login when you experience the type of problem I've been having. What do you think?

Comment: I've always *assumed* the welcome banner is necessary. It allows the scripts to set the cookie for the specific domain name. An auto-reload could do that too, but is just a bit too annoying in cases like that, I *assume*. (Note that clicking login would get you such auto-reload. Just not when landing on the home page.) That said: a fully automatic login might in fact just be hidden redirects, hence not solving your problem, I *assume*. But given the number of assumptions, maybe your request does make sense.

Comment: Ah, here it is: [Why does it says welcome back -user- click here to “refresh page”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73191/why-does-it-says-welcome-back-user-click-here-to-refresh-page).

Comment: @Arjan, did you see my (under par) answer? Anyway, I guess the button could force auto-login to the sites and thus overriding the default behavior, but that's an assumption of mine... ouch.