# Logged out, but still logged in?(not duplicate as answer for that duplicate is not my issue)

Tags: support, login, logout, cookies

I found this question and still asking this again since I have clicked 'logout' button properly.(Two times, on top once and then the logout button appeared after this). After all these, I just clicked in the text box for openid, then It showed that I have logged in again. I am using chrome and it was in incognito mode. I cleared the cookies in content settings once.(But I don't see a reason for doing that since the message shows that your local settings will be cleared).

I tried 2 or 3 times and got this. And once I got the error saying this is our fault it is not you message.

Comment: You have to log out of your OpenID provider as well as Stack Overflow. Otherwise, you will be automatically logged back in.

Comment: got it again,"Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

Comment: I first searched this before asking, found the answer and it didn't suit in my case and then I asked the same.

Comment: Related: [How to log out completely on stackexchange sites using OpenID without closing my browser?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92326)

Comment: Related: [Log out of StackOverflow but it won't really](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89554)

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone for your help. Hope these links will fix my worries.

Comment: It's expected for you to be logged in again if you are still logged into your OpenID / OAuth provider and click on _that_ particular provider - you'll auto login again, but I'm curious to know with more detail where exactly you're seeing the whoops/exception page?