# How do you logout of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, logout

How do you log out of Stack Overflow? There isn't any logout button.

[image: Screenshot of a user profile]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a map that will help you find the long lost button:

[image]

Comment: I would +1 this, but the circle isn't freehand.  Red freehand circles are a must with screenshots here.

Comment: @Servy freehand circles are too cute, I was afraid that the user will not concentrate on the map directions...

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers say, the "log out" link is now hidden inside the "Stack Exchange" menu in the top <s>left</s> right corner of the page.

Unfortunately, **just clicking that link is generally not enough** to log you fully out of Stack Overflow — if you don't *also* [log out of your OpenID provider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92326/how-to-log-out-completely-on-stackexchange-sites-using-openid-without-closing-my), you'll just be [automatically logged back in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work) when you next visit SO.  (Yes, that happens even if you're using Stack Exchange to log in — the Stack Exchange OpenID provider is a separate system from the actual sites like SO.)

In practice, if you ever need to log out of SO (e.g. if you're using SO from a public computer), the easiest ways to do that are to either:

1. use the Private Browsing / Incognito mode in your browser when visiting Stack Overflow, or
2. if you've already made the mistake of logging in to SO outside Private Browsing mode, clear all cookies and other private data from the browser.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first answer that actually addresses the issue of not being able to log out. However, on SE there isn't even a log out link any more. The drop down menu isn't there.

Comment: @user329044: The menu was moved to the top *right* corner in the latest top bar redesign. (Also, AIUI, there have been some changes to the SE login system since I wrote this answer that *may* mean that just clicking the "log out" link is now enough if you're *not* using an external OpenID provider but just logged into your SE account with an e-mail address and a password. But I'm not 100% sure about that.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you possibly update the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Click the StackExchange arrow on the left. There is a log out link in there (right side)

Answer (score 0):

[Image](http://prntscr.com/2pn17q)

This is because Stack Overflow doesn't want us to leave, we're a lovely community fully of magic and you shall not leave us alone.

Answer (score -1):

Press on StackExchange in the left corner, there is a log out link