# I can't automatically log in to a site where I have not created an account

Tags: support, myopenid, auto-login

I'm having this problem after migrating away from MyOpenID and setting my SE Open ID as primary.

I just tried clicking on theoretical cs and I got the Q&A notification bar. I'm using the 'SE open ID' now as main ID. I think my browser is OK for global auth, [I just checked](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help). I'm on Ubuntu Firefox.

[image: I clicked on 'log in']
First I clicked on 'Log in'

[image: No cigar]
As you can see, no luck.

[image: My current state]
Currently my meta.stackoverflow profile shows this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what exactly happened? The [way the Global Login works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work) the MyOpenID problem shouldn't cause an issue at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I just checked, and you do not have a cstheory account. Under no circumstances do we ever automatically create accounts.**

So long as you have created an account on the target site, there are a few ways global auto-login can fail, largly based on oddball browser or network configurations. What does this say:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/network-login-help

Comment: I says 'Success'.

Comment: I think this should be changed to 'feature-request'. I do not think SE should create the account automatically, but I do believe SE should always acknowledge the logged on users. This means the Q&A top notification should not be shown. The StackExchange - User notification bar should have a 'create account' link.

Comment: I believe SE has overloaded the meaning of 'log in' with 'create account' and that creates confusion (at least it baffled me).