# The Global Network Auto-Login cognitive trap

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, auto-login

This is a graphical representation of the cognitive trap.
[image: Cognitive Trap]

To understand the trap, let's look at the log-on states of a single site.
[image: Single Site log-on]

As you can see, the Y state doesn't exist. However, when another site is added we can look at the multiple site log-on states.
[image: Multiple Site log-on]

Here, the Y state does exist, because it makes sense to be able to be logged into the network without having an explicit user on the 2nd site.

This is the correct representation without the trap.
[image: Visitor Profile]

As you can see, the C user role doesn't have to automatically create a user account on the 2nd site.

The feature request is to create a Visitor profile. Somebody that can visit any site on the StackExchange network without being logged out. The benefits of having this profile are 1) No 'Welcome to Q&A' banner and 2) One click account creation.

1) is self-evident.
2) maybe it's a bug, but when I click on 'log in' on a 2nd site, I never have my account created. I always have to type my OpenID+Password.

Comment: Can we expect every question you'll ever ask to contain some buzzword from a sociology/psychology/behavioral science book glossar?

Comment: By the way, your posts sometimes have a tendency to read like rants... Especially when you end them with *"AmIRight?"* I don't exactly understand what you're proposing here, either. Automatic account creation? [We don't do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96696/i-cant-automatically-log-in-to-a-site-where-i-have-not-created-an-account/96824#96824).

Comment: IT'S A TRAP!!! http://youtu.be/dddAi8FF3F4

Comment: I don't understand the point you're making with respect to cognitive traps/biases. Could you clarify?

Comment: @balpha, could you recommend a good book, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @Jeremy, I hope the edit(s) are clearer.

Comment: @Cody, yes the 'AmIRight' is a bit ranty, and NO, I'm not talking about automatic account creation.

Comment: @balpha, I've just created [a discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102625/se-multi-site-analysis) about this. I hope that clarifies the cognitive trap, a little bit. Again, sorry about this awfully written question/rant. Thanks for giving me a (another) reason why I'm being downvoted constantly (apart from my poor writing skills).

Answer (score 13):

Look. Sometimes when I come on SE site which I'm not associated with, I just wanna see some posts, but I don't want to be associated there. If I would have account on each SE site, there would be big mess in my "accounts" tab.

When I want to associate my account, I just click on login and press "Facebook" button. It's all I need to do in order to associate my main account. Is it so hard? No. Just 2-button clicks

Comment: How can you stand to read posts without being logged in, though? I keep clicking the vote arrows and *nothing happens*! I don't get my banana pellet...

Comment: That's my point. I am not after an automatic account creation, but after a correct 'visitor' treatment (see my edit(s) above).

Comment: @CodyGray: [you](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7818/gluten-free-replacement-to-coat-something-with-before-roasting-to-obtain-crust) can't vote, but there is anonymous feedback everytime...