# SE multi-site analysis

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, auto-login

Let's take a look at the login model for multiple sites. 1 site or more, with account or not.

[image: Z-Order]

Let me explain this table.

- A: Unknown user arrives at a SE-site.
- B: Registered user has an account at a SE-site.
- C: Registered user arrives at another SE-site.
- D: Registered user has an account at another SE-site.

The natural order to transverse through this is from A to D (z-order).

- User role A is an Unknown user (either new or logged out).
- User role B is a logged in user.
- User role C does not exist in SE (visitor role).
- User role D is a logged in user.

Let's look at the actions that any role can take.
[image: Actions]

The user B can go to D with the Global Network Auto-Login feature.

The visitor role does not exist. On SE any user that visits a site where he/she does not have an account, (s)he'll be treated as an unknown user (role A).

I propose the C role (visitor) should be created. Any B role (known) user that visits another site is known to the system, but has no badges nor points at the other site. A 'create account' link is presented, so the user can become a D role user with one click. Otherwise, the visitor behaves like an A role user (unknown).

Note that I haven't mentioned the auto-create account feature. That is because I am against it, just like anybody else.

Comment: I knew who posted this as soon as I saw the first table. I'm not sure if that's a good thing or not

Comment: @Micheal, me neither.

Comment: **tl;dr** Replace the login "link" with  "create account" when someone is known to have an account on other SE sites, to more accurately reflect their relationship with the network.

Comment: I'm not *opposed* to this, but I don't really see the problem it is trying to solve, either. I'm happy with other SE sites treating me as a stranger until I click the "login" button. It's never been a problem for me.

Comment: @Eat more Twisters, it's to prevent the 'Welcome to Q&A' banner and to be able to have a one click login.

Comment: So, do you have the feature marking typos with red squiggly lines *inverted* to where correctly spelled words are marked? There's something wrong with your spreadsheet app.

Comment: @Cody. Nah, must be in Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of technical reasons not to do this, and it's awfully minor gain.

The primary one is that a global log in check (to see if a user is a "visitor") is quite expensive, and would adversely affect page ready times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wouldn't this check be just as expensive as the Global Network Auto-Login check (that's done asynchronous)?