# SE multi-site strategy - measure it

Tags: discussion, site-stats

I'd like to ask the SE dev team to reconsider the 'status-declined' tag for [my proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102625/se-multi-site-analysis) of creating a 'Visitor' role. I'm asking because I think it's an important feature, but I don't want you to take my word for it. I'd like you to measure it!

How many registered users go and visit other sites where they don't have associated accounts? Supposing only 10% of the users per month, that's a whopping 75.000 users (as per the latest blog post) that assume the visitor role.

I think this is a) constructive, b) different than the original proposal.

**Edit** Can anybody explain why this question is still closed?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: It'd help if you clarify what you mean by "visitors" in the last sentence. Non-registered users? It seems like you posted the standard "there should be one login" spiel and then added on a random sentence at the end to avoid making it a duplicate

Comment: @Michael I thought [you'd know](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102625/se-multi-site-analysis) what I was talking about.

Comment: @Robert I'm asking why there is no(t going to be) a visitor role. That is somebody that's registered on one site, but visiting another site without account association. There must be statistics about the number of registered users visiting other sites. Hope that clarifies some.

Comment: @GUI, if your questions is specifically, 'How many visitors are there on a daily/monthly basis?', then a change in title may result in more useful responses.

Comment: @M.Tibbits thanks for the suggestion, but there are two questions here. The main one is about 'why' visitors are treated as if they were new users.

Comment: @Robert, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

> To clarify the 'visitor' role is a person that's registered on site 1, but not on site 2. On site 2 he/she will only look around.

If you aren't registered on site then then you *are* a visitor. Unless you register, the GlobalAuth doesn't kick in.

> If this estimate is right, then SE has been impolite to 400.000 users so far. I call it impolite when somebody doesn't salute me, even if they don't know my name.

Impolite, how? I do visit other network sites once in a while, but I'm *not* interested in creating an account. I'm just another anon. user. You mention it's impolite to **not** salute you, yet you don't want to be identified as per the above quote.  Huh?

Comment: Visitor is registered on the SE network. If somebody visits site 2, he should be known (GUI Junkie, Sathya) but without reputation or badges. At this moment you get the 'Welcome to Q&A' banner. So, yes, I want to be identified, but I do not want to (automatically) create an account.

Comment: And the example I gave was about people meting in the street. I might know your face, but not your name but I salute you because I'm polite. SE knows my name, or at least my nick.