# With cookies deactivated, how does stackoverflow log me in automaticly?

Tags: discussion

I'm using Opera, with the option to discard all cookies from one session to the next. So, how does stackoverflow log me in automatically, if I didn't visit the site for several days?

Opera version:

```
Version 11.51
Build 1087
Platform Linux
System x86_64, 2.6.32-33-generic
```

Comment: how do you log in? openid, userpass?

Comment: Most likely this is done using [HTML5 web storage](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/web-storage/).

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange uses HTML5 LocalStorage for its [global network auto-login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/). This means that even if your cookies are removed, it will read your login token from LocalStorage, and automatically generate login cookies again.

> We use HTML 5 Local Storage for global authentication, at our centralized domain stackauth.com. Now, this does require a modern browser, though not unreasonably so: IE8+, Chrome, Safari, FireFox 3.6+, and Opera 10.61+ are all supported.

You can read all about the technical background [in this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274).