# How can Stack Overflow automatically login after resetting Safari?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, auto-login

Recently I noticed the following remarkable automatic login behavior:

After resetting Safari:

[image: Image of Safari reset dialog box]

Stack Overflow is always automatically logged in again:

[image: Auto Login]

I always assumed to be logged out **everywhere** after resetting Safari.
Apparently Stack Overflow is still able to automatically login again.

How can Stack Overflow automatically login after resetting Safari?
And how can I prevent this behavior? In my opinion this is not secure.

Comment: This has never happened to me in Chrome. Strange...

Comment: See also [Global Network Auto-Login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) on the blog, and [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274) here on Meta. (And [How to clear all HTML5 local storage from Safari?](http://superuser.com/questions/236558/how-to-clear-all-html5-local-storage-from-safari) on Super User.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe Stack Overflow uses [Web Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage) to locally store login preferences, and your OpenID/OAuth provider might be doing that as well. If you’ve enabled the Develop menu (Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar), you can fire the Web Inspector (Develop > Show Web Inspector) and select Resources > Local Storage to inspect what has been locally stored by stackoverflow.com (in my case, meta.stackoverflow.com has stored a key-value pair with key `login-prefs`).

I also believe you’re using and ‘old’ version of Safari. Version 5.1.1 (7534.51.22), when asked to reset Safari, shows a ‘Remove all website data’ option as the last checkbox whilst your screenshot doesn’t list that option. If I select that checkbox when resetting Safari, I need to log on to Stack Overflow again, so it certainly removes Web storage.

You should also be able to remove local storage with Preferences > Privacy > Remove All Website Data…, at least on Safari 5.1.1. Furthermore, the Details… button shows how a given Web site is using local data: cache, cookies or local (Web) storage.

Comment: Nice change; previous versions did not allow for deleting this at all!

Comment: By the way: one should not look at the current site, but at http://stackauth.com and then peek into `localStorage.getItem('GlobalLogin')`. See also [Global Network Auto-Login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) on the blog, and [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274) here on Meta.

Comment: @Arjan Oh, nice. Thanks for the references.