# How is stackoverflow.com be able to automatically log me in even after Safari's cookies have been cleared?

Tags: discussion, design, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can Stack Overflow automatically login after resetting Safari?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110291/how-can-stack-overflow-automatically-login-after-resetting-safari)

How is stackoverflow.com be able to automatically logged me in even after Safari's cookies have been cleared.  I also cleared Safari' cache and restarted iPad.

I want to implement a similar feature at my site, so I'm wondering how SO is achieving this behaviour.

Comment: Are you using an OpenID to log in?

Comment: @NoelM I don't think so. He's probably looking for a method to implement the same feature at his own website.

Comment: @Rob W - if that's the case, then the question should state that.

Comment: @NoelM **"This is a programming question. So don't move to another site."**

Comment: @Rob W Where's the programming question?

Comment: Just stating that it's a programming question doesn't make it one.

Comment: @Rob W: Yes, I used Open ID and I selected not to stay login.

Comment: I will stated it again:  This is programming question!

Comment: @RobW You can't login to StackExchange group without an OpenID :) all those login options are OpenID credentials.

Comment: You might want to edit the question so that it looks like one, too. Like, "How can I keep users logged in even after they've cleared cookies and cache, just like SO does?"

Comment: See [Global Network Auto-Login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) and [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stackoverflow is using **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)** to save preferences regarding logging in using OpenID. It's also a form of persistance, similar but not equal to cookies.

You can read this information by typing the following code at the main site:

```
console.log(localStorage["login-prefs"])
```

See also [Global Network Auto-Login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) on the blog, and [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274) here on Meta.

Comment: I have some background with .net and used cookies.  But did not know this stuff!

Comment: Actually, one should not look at the current site, but at http://stackauth.com and then peek into `localStorage.getItem('GlobalLogin')`, @user. Also, just typing `localStorage` is enough to see all contents for that current site. (That is: in Firebug and the console of any Web Kit browser.)