# Stack Exchange OpenID credentials not removed on logout, allowing insecure re-login

Tags: discussion, user-interface, stack-exchange-openid, authentication

The cookies for subdomain, 'openid.stackexchange.com' are not, as claimed, actually removed from the browser upon logging out of stackexchange.com, but they should be.

Applies to:
* stackexchange.com, date: January 8, 2012

Desired result:

- Upon logging out of Stack Exchange, Stack Exchange OpenID local credentials stored 'in your browser' (or stored anywhere on the user's computer) should actually be deleted, as promised. For example, Stack Exchange OpenID browser cookies actually should be deleted.
- Logging in again should require explicitly entering one's credentials again. This might be email address and password.
- It is misleading to claim that (all relevant) 'local credentials in your browser' are deleted, since anyone else sitting down at the same computer can merely click the login links and immediately be accepted as the same, previous user! (See procedure to duplicate, below.)

Procedure to duplicate the problem in FireFox:

Versions (Menu-Help-Troubleshooting Information-Application Basics-User Agent):
* Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1

- Start FireFox.
- In Firefox's cookies manager (Menu-Tools-Options-Privacy), click the button, 'Exceptions', enter stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com, and each time, click the button, 'Allow for Session'.
- Click the button, 'Close'.
- Click the button, 'Show Cookies'. Type, 'Stack', select stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com if they are there, and each time, click the button, 'Remove Cookies'.
- Close Firefox.
- Start Firefox.
- Close webmail notifier windows.
- Log out of Gmail.
- Wait ten seconds.
- Click the back button on the browser to make sure one is not still logged in to Gmail.
- Open a tab for, https://stackexchange.com/ .
- In [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript), if you have it, allow the domains, 'stackexchange.com' and, 'sstatic.net' and refresh.
- Click the link at the top, 'login'.
- On the resulting page, click the box, 'Log in with Stack Exchange.'
- Enter one's Gmail email address and Stack Exchange password, which results in a successful Stack Exchange login.
- Click the link at the top, 'logout'.
- The resulting web page has an orange button labeled, 'logout', above which is presented the text, 'Clicking Log Out will clear all local credentials in your browser.'
- Click the orange button labeled, 'logout'.

One might think that one has completely logged out safely from Stack Exchange, with no possibility of simply clicking back in. But, not true!

- Now the page has the link at the top, 'login'.
- However, the Firefox Cookie Manager still shows cookies under domains, 'stackexchange.com' and 'openid.stackexchange.com'.
- Click the link at the top, 'login'.
- On the resulting page, again click the box, 'Log in with Stack Exchange.'
- See the login unexpectedly succeed, without entering any email address or Stack Exchange password!

Comment: SeaMonkey isn't supported [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)

Comment: As an aside: how is *"clear all local credentials"* the same as *"remove all cookies"*? (It should indeed clear the relevant *contents* of any cookies though, if applicable.) Also, for further testing, beware of [the stackauth.com domain and its usage of HTML5 Local Storage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work) too. (I've not verified the behavior you're describing above.)

Comment: Do you think the bug is for Stack Exchange as an OpenID *provider*, or the Stack Exchange family of sites as OpenID *consumers*? (I don't seem to run into this using my own OpenID provider, and of course I am not expecting Stack Exchange sites to clear any cookies from my OpenID provider. But I've no SE OpenID account to test with.)

Comment: This happens with the google, and almost every other OpenID provider as well, what's the issue here?  You logged out of our **sites**, not the **OpenID provider**.  For example, you can do this logging in with a google account anywhere as well, only logging out of *google* will require credentials again...you didn't log out of `openid.stackexchange.com` which is it's own distinct provider (which you can use on other sites, not just ours), only the Q&A sites.  IMO, the logout button on *our* sites shouldn't introduce odd re-enter-credentials behavior on *other* sites you used our provider with.

Comment: @NickCraver SSO is pretty unintuitive, and particularly so when the provider and consumer are on the same TLD. Considering that SE is now trying to appeal to relatively non-tech-savvy users, it should be considered a security problem that so many users will not understand how logging out of their account works.

Comment: With FireFox also, the bad thing happened (as edited above). The StackExchange webpage's claim to log users out is misleading (see above). Both altering cookie contents or deleting entire cookies would work, but deleting entire cookies is better, because more apparent. Removing the cookies for just the domain, 'openid.stackexchange.com' was enough to cause the credentials to be re-requested and prevented the insecure re-login. This is StackExchange's problem as an OpenID provider. Websites outside the StackExchange family trusting the StackExchange OpenID provider would be insecurely accessed.

Comment: @NickCraver, What made you think I logged out of 'your' sites? I did not log out of any Q&A site. I went through the log out procedure on the webpage with URL, 'stackexchange.com', thus I think I did, as you recommend, log out of the StackExchange OpenID provider (but unsuccessfully). I never clicked any link for another Stack family webpage (during the test procedure). (It is irrelevant that I am posting on StackOverflow.)

Comment: @NickCraver, the logging out URL was http://stackexchange.com/users/logout?returnurl=%2f .

Comment: @JeremyBanks, not merely users not understanding, but it seems logging out (of StackExchange OpenID provider) is not actually working or functional!

Comment: @NickCraver, BTW, on the StackExchange.com webpage, when I clicked the link at the top, 'meta', I was brought here, to Meta StackOverflow. For discussing issues with StackExchange, where is the best place?

Comment: @Arjan, to answer your question, I do thinkUpon logging out, Stack Exchange local credentials stored 'in your browser' (or stored anywhere on the user's computer) should actually be deleted, as promised.

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell Yes, this is the correct place. There used to be a distinct meta.StackExchange but it was merged into meta.StackOverflow.

Comment: @Arjan, in answer, I indeed think Stack Exchange as an OpenID provider has a bug. (As edited above), Otherwise, anyone sitting at the same computer can merely click the login links and be erroneously authenticated as the previous user.

Comment: As Nick mentioned, logging out from `http://stackexchange.com/` is something very different than logging out from the OpenID provider at `http://openid.stackexchange.com/`. You need to log out of your [Stack Exchange OpenID](http://openid.stackexchange.com), otherwise yes, the OpenID provider can still authenticate you.

Comment: @Tim is correct, I think the confusion here is the simply shared TLD, think of it as openid.stackexchangeopenidprovider.com instead, would you assume you've logged out there when logging out of stackexchange.com?

Comment: @JeremyBanks, I agree with you that logging out of StackExchange currently has a security problem, especially for new users, particularly those who don't already use OpenID.

Comment: @TimStone, NickCraver, thanks for making it obvious to me (previously not an OpenID user) what happened, and I agree, naturally a subdomain is very different! So, literally, the question is answered. However, StackExchange.com claims it registers new users for itself, not for an OpenID subdomain; at least it wasn't obvious, which seems a UI problem.

Comment: @NickCraver The OpenID provider should know if the account is used for sites other than SE, so you could make a distinction there. If it is only used for SE sites, have the logout button log you out of the SE OpenID provider completely. And display a notice on logging out if you don't log out of OpenID, to remind users of that.

Comment: @Fabian - I totally disagree "if X then X" is *never* more intuitive behavior, if the goal here is to lessen the confusion level...having it behave differently for some users based on where *else* they used their Stack Exchange OpenID is the absolute worst way to make it simpler IMO.

Comment: @NickCraver, rabbit suggested RP remember OP; after RP logs out redirect the user to OP: http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-general/2009-April/017840.html  Any OP page showing OP login status is sufficient. Inconvenient but secure; it's also potentially user-configurable.

Comment: I edited the question title & text to refer to the Stack Exchange OpenID cookies, because that's where credentials are stored; the new question has been literally answered no longer.

Comment: I think it's probably worth asking a new question which cuts out all the technical discussions and goes directly to the user confusion issue, best highlighted by @Jeremy Bank's answer (IMO)

Comment: @Benjol, now, per your suggestion, I have 'ask[ed] a new [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119045/how-can-stack-exchange-avoid-misleading-new-registrants-by-hiding-the-underlying) ...to cut out all the technical discussions and go directly to the user confusion issue, best highlighted by JeremyBank's answer'.

Comment: In your repro steps, you do a lot of abnormal cookie magic.  If that's actually necessary for the repro for the average user, then I wouldn't worry about this at all because you're setting things up quite specially.  I can't verify because stackexchange just hangs for me when logging in with their own OP right now (a temporary bug I suppose).

Comment: As I answered for your last question, I believe the merit here is orthogonal to the protocol used.  It's simply that logging out of stackexchange.com does not log you out of another site under the same TLD.  If you whittle it down to just the little issue, you might get more traction here.

Comment: @AndrewArnott, Stack Exchange Network (regardless of domain names) at question time had global signout exclusive of openid.stackexchange.com. Having two Stack Exchange OpenID servers would improve the naive user experience, were the default server included in the global signout.

Comment: @arjan, why don't you create a special email account and use it to create a SE OpenID account? With it, simultaneously logged out of every SE site, without being given an opportunity for logout of the SE OpenID provider, and see the message 'Clear Global Credentials' displayed? And then see how you feel about yet merely click-logging back in?

Comment: @NickCraver, Tim Stone, since the SE family of websites is a family, and it controls the SE OpenID provider, then people expect it to be responsible and prompt for a family logout. Support: 1. "[regardless of the login flow you choose, you must also offer an explicit 'Log Out' option that also logs the user out of Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/)." 2. "[Major OpenID providers (both Google and Yahoo) do provide Single Sign-Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968814/how-to-add-logout-feature-to-an-openid-enabled-site#comment4464700_1968855)."

Comment: @TimStone, IMO people expect the SE family be responsible like Google, Yahoo & Facebook and prompt them with the choice of a family logout.

Comment: related: [Storing Stack Overflow login details in local storage considered harmful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188261)

Comment: I'm left with two alternatives to work around this inconvenience: 1) start a new private window in Firefox, or 2) disable the **dom.storage.enabled** option in the Firefox configuration (about:config).

Comment: Related: *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*

Answer (score 23):

Single sign on is a great goal.

Single sign out should have accompanied it.

It didn't.

OpenID does not provide a mechanism nor a standard process for single sign out.

If I sign into Stack Exchange, then logout of my OpenID provider, the next user can still use my Stack Exchange account.

If I instead log out of Stack Exchange without signing out of my OpenID provider, the next person can log back into my Stack Exchange account without signing into my OpenID provider again.

I have to sign out of both Stack Exchange and my OpenID provider to ensure that I'm signed out completely.

This is counter-intuitive, and education is the only thing that might help resolve the issue.

### Solution

I suggest that when a user logs out of Stack Exchange the next page shown suggests they also log out of their OpenID provider to make sure the next user cannot easily log back into their account on this computer. It should link to their OpenID provider's logout page (if any) to make this process simple and intuitive.

Comment: For those curious about single sign out solutions, check out https://www.google.com/search?q=single+sign+out+openid - you'll find that many discussions have taken place about this on stackoverflow itself, as others try to find a good solution to this complex issue.

Comment: The first part of your solution seems feasible to me. Nice. But: as OpenID does not specify a standard logout procedure (right?), how would OpenID consumers know what the URL of a logout page for a specific OpenID provider would be? (Surely SE does not know what the logout page of my self-hosted OpenID provider is, as I have no such page.)

Comment: @Arjan, By OpenID consumers, do you mean the Relying Parties (RP)? RP would not need to know the OpenID Provider's logout page. After logging out of an RP, the OP's root URL (homepage) would be a good fallback to redirect browsers to, because it probably shows the login status; anyway, it would remind the naive user.

Comment: Good suggestion, I just made it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119404/154510) as well.

Answer (score 16):

Arjan points out that logging in requires you to explicitly select an OpenID provider<sup>1</sup>. This is true, but this is not made obvious to the user. Consider a user who is not particularly tech-savvy nor familiar with the concept of single sign-on (except for that one time they used Twitter to login to yfrog). This may or may not represent a typical current user, but it represents many of the users Stack Exchange wants to have so it's a valuable perspective to consider.

Say that such a user decides to login to a Stack Exchange site. They're presented with the set of choices below and pick the option they're most familiar with from other sites: the big link "click here to sign up".

[image]

This link doesn't do anything unusual like send them to a separate domain or section of the site, it just loads the registration form into the page. After they've signed up, the email confirmation link even redirects you back to the original site. It's a very seamless process, much like signing up on any other site.

Should we expect this user to have noticed that they've done something different than when they've registered on other websites? The login sidebar mentions OpenID, but most users who actually read it will probably think it's just referring to the MyOpenID link, unless they they were previously aware of OpenID. OpenID is not referenced anywhere else. Granted, the registration sidebar says the account can be used for any Stack Exchange site, but taken together this is not enough to expect the user to understand that the login system is separate from the site, nor that logging out securely is a two-step process.

Users who don't understand the system they're using are much more likely to put themselves at risk, most easily by forgetting or not knowing the second step to log out. I know Stack Exchange accounts aren't the most valuable thing in the world<sup>2</sup>, but for what they're worth this should be considered a significant security issue.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Some are actually OAuth, but the the page doesn't mention that.

<sup>2</sup> ...though the Stack Exchange OpenID password requirements may make you think otherwise.</sub>

Comment: The Stack Exchange OpenID account is even more valuable than just for the Stack Exchange Network since, as suggested on the page you screen-captured, I presume anyone can use it to create accounts on any of thousands of websites, then perhaps neglect to log off from a shared (public, or at a party) computer.

Comment: Not only is the 'require[ment] to explicitly select an OpenID provider...not made obvious to the user', it is hidden by design.

Comment: This seems to have been resolved by changes to the login/signup flow.

Answer (score 10):

For some time I figured that your last bullet,

> - See the login unexpectedly succeed, without entering any email address or Stack Exchange password!

...implied that you did not do *anything* to initiate the login.

But, as your penultimate bullet states: you actually clicked one of the OpenID buttons, which makes Stack Overflow (or any other SE site, in its role as OpenID consumer) delegate the login to that very provider. For that very provider, you're still logged in, so it tells the consumer who you are, without asking you for any credentials.

This behavior is totally the same as that of my non-SE OpenID provider (though I need to enter a URL manually because my provider is not one of the quick access buttons).

[image: Known OpenID providers]

Comment: The button does not distinguish StackExchange from the StackExchange OpenID provider; this unexpectedness is something the naive user experiences after registering with StackExchange. The problem is peculiar to the OpenID.StackExchange provider, since users know how to log off the others.

Comment: Of course, I clicked the Stack Exchange OpenID button. I never said I didn't; you said I implied this but I did not. I said I did not enter any email address or Stack Exchange password. Hiding from a naive, new Stack Exchange user, they resided in a cookie managed by the Stack Exchange Network. I am well aware that currently one of the implementations of logging in to Stack Exchange is through openid.stackexchange.com; but merely a few clicks was sufficient to complete the login, which on a shared computer an attacker can do also; therein lies one of the problems.

Comment: The other problem is a potential danger to Stack Exchange regarding its public image.

Comment: I just tried this out on stackexhange.com, and I didn't need to push any of the buttons to get me logged back in automatically: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211583/stackexchange-com-logs-me-in-automatically-on-the-login-page

Answer (score 7):

The Stack Exchange Network (Relying Party, RP), before any kind of logout, should ask whether logging out from the current OpenID Provider (OP) is also desired, as suggested in mailing list, 'openid-general' by an Andrew Arnott here: http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-general/2009-April/017856.html and by someone else here : http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-general/2009-April/017840.html .

This would be, in effect, merely following Google's practice of logging one out of the entire identity simultaneously, which presumably we are all familiar with.

If the answer is no, the RP logout can proceed.

If the answer is yes, first provide a link to some page (the home page is a fallback) of the current OP (openid.stackexchange.com in this case), unless unnecessary (like Google, FaceBook and maybe Yahoo). The RP logout should be refused until the OP service replies as logged out, then the RP logout can proceed.

The problem is, naive users know when they have signed into Google. They don't know when they have signed into openid.stackexchange.com, because they aren't told about it. (Please focus on users, now.)

After researching, I know more of what's happening (technically). Many newly registered users don't. These are the ones naive to OpenID and not selecting Facebook, Google or Yahoo but instead selecting, 'log in with Stack Exchange'. They have a security problem, unless the Stack Exchange Network does as described above.

Comment: While a mailing list opinion is great, I'd expect anything labeled "Correct" to have a reference to the official documentation.  Otherwise it appears to be a suggestion made by one person whom we know little about.

Comment: I would happily rephrase my answer to, 'The StackExchange family of websites should...' if that would be better! :)

Comment: Of one of the openid-general mailing list posters (rabbit) I know little, but privately @AndrewArnott has confirmed to me he is the Andrew Arnott who made the other post.

Answer (score -4):

This is not really insecure (depends on user education) since **clearing all browser private data** (i.e cookies, cache, active connection, etc...) resolves the automatic **login redirection** and force to input credential for next login/authentication. Of course it's not **convenient**

**EDIT** : As @Martin said

> LocalStorage isn't cleared when deleting browser's private data

So here I provide some more precision :
I don't really know/care if **LocalStorage** is cleared at all. What I want is to be forced to input my credentials when I try to **Login** after I clicked on **Logout** (using my stackexchange openID creds). I've even seen clients using **OAuth** which behave like that
My using of the term **"delete browser private data" may be inappropriate** to define what I really did. But after doing what I said then stackexchange asked me to input my credentials (and that wasn't the same when I just deleted cookies).
So what I did in Firefox corresponds to what is described in this link (as I haven't enough reputation to upload screenshot) : [Support.Mozilla : Clear Recent History](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Clear%20Recent%20History#w_how-do-i-clear-my-history) (With all checkbox checked in "Details")

Comment: This is a lie. LocalStorage isn't cleared when deleting browser's private data.

Comment: @Martin I don't know/care if LocalStorage is cleared or not. But when I do CTRL+SHIFT+DELETE with Firefox (and asume all checkbox are checked) then stackexchange ask me to input my credentials when I click on "Login" again. I can post a screenshot if you want :p