# auto logout feature and closing of session when closing the browser window for stackoverflow and meta stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I'm using google chrome browser. After logging in to stackoverflow , when I leave the system idle for long time or closing the browser does not affecting the logged in session. when I open the browser again and load stackoverflow site, session remains exist and I m able to post questions.

The feature request is , When I close the browser, ideally the session or login should be closed, when the user opens the browser again, they should login again, may be for security purposes. Because when I users are using public system, then the login may be misused if not properly logged out. We can click on logout and close the session typically. But mostly the great sites, have this feature. So thought of sharing it.

Comment: Why not just click "logout"? The vast majority of non-critical sites on the internet keep sessions alive even when your browser window is closed.

Comment: Stack Overflow really doesn't store anything of that much personal value that it really needs automatic logging out. It's already extremely difficult to delete your own content, and editing a lot of your posts at once will automatically flag them for self-vandalism and action can be taken.

Comment: Just to be sure you know: using log out in these sites, might still leave your OpenID session alive, @waiwai933.

Comment: Use the incognito in the public

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The feature request is , When I close the browser, ideally the session or login should be closed

That is pretty much impossible for *us* to implement, but trivial for *you* to enable.

[image: chrome content settings dialog with highlighted "clear cookies on browser closing" option]

Comment: Actually, it would be trivial for SE to implement this - simply use session cookies (without an expiration date). But changing the settings in the particular browser to "Allow local data to be set for the current session only" is still the better solution.

Comment: No, @Wladimir, see my answer. It's not just Stack Exchange that is involved here.

Comment: @Arjan: The OP is asking about SE, not about his OpenID provider ;)

Comment: (Interesting how the radio buttons do not mention *"and other site and plug-in data*", which I guess refers to Web Storage, Web SQL, Flash etc.)

Comment: So you're expecting that the OP is fine with then just clicking "log in" and then being logged in without being asked for any password, @Wladimir...?

Comment: @Arjan: No, I expect that the OP doesn't use OpenID which is why this possibility didn't even occur to him. Note that you would still have to know the OpenID identifier to log in - technically speaking, you will be logged out of SE. Btw, am I the only one feeling that this discussion is pointless?

Comment: btw, what is OP?

Comment: @user617597 "original poster", in this case: you.

Answer (score 4):

Unless this would be a user setting that defaults to "no", I'd really not want that.

That said: many OpenID providers (outside the control of Stack Exchange) would still have you logged in, and then tell Stack Exchange a new login [is just fine when it asks again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118247/stack-exchange-openid-credentials-not-removed-on-logout-allowing-insecure-re-lo/118422#118422).

So: using public computers, take responsibility yourself. Easiest: use some incognito/private browsing mode before logging in.