# StackExchange.com logs me in automatically on the login page

Tags: bug, login, stackexchange.com, logout, stack-exchange-openid

When I go to the main stackexchange.com site, and login, then logout, after I try to login again, I am automatically logged in, without having to enter any account details.

Pics:

[image]

Then I press login:

[image]

Note, that I didn't fill out anything, it just logged me in. When I logout explicitly on the site, I get logged out, but I can still just click the login page and get logged in automatically, without needing to enter my details.

Notes:

- I am using an own OpenID URL that delegates to SE's OpenID provider
- Browser: Chrome
- After logout local storage and session storage are empty. The following cookies are present: `d`, `mc`, `__cfduid`, `__qca`, `__utma`, `__utmb`, `__utmc`, `__utmz`, `ASP.NET_SessionId`, `gauthed`.

EDIT: If you closed this question, because it is a duplicate, please note that at the duplicate question the poster [actually clicked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118247/stack-exchange-openid-credentials-not-removed-on-logout-allowing-insecure-re-lo#comment311889_118422) on the SE provider to arrive at the auto-login page. In my case I *did not* have to click on any of the provider buttons, which means simply arriving at the login page will do an auto-login, essentally preventing logging in as any other user (which, if it is by design, is probably wrong)

Comment: This is by design. Clear your cookies or use InPrivate/Incognito mode.

Comment: If you're logged in to any other site on that computer, it will also do this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Didn't see that question, thanks!

Comment: Going through that link it seems, there they click the SE button on the login page to get autologin. I haven't pressed any of the buttons, I just went to that page, and got logged in instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed now