# Stack Exchange doesn't let me logout easily

Tags: discussion, support, bug, openid, logout

I have read several similar questions before posting this. So, please don't mark it duplicate before reading this completely.

Few days ago I tried to logout of my [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) account. Since I was using Stack Exchange Openid, I also logout from the [openid](http://openid.stackexchange.com). But instead of permanent logout I was expecting, on clicking login button I was automatically logged in without asking login details.

By doing some research I found that there is a `Local Storage` cookie from the [`stackauth.com`](http://stackauth.com) domain that is preventing me from logging out. I then deleted the cookie and I was permanently logged out successfully.

Now, It doesn't make sense if I want to logout from stack exchange, I have to:

A) First logout of the stackexchange site

B) Then logout from openid.stackexchange.com site

C) And finally delete the Local Storage cookie from stackauth.com domain.

I don't think that most of the users are going to do all three steps. Most of them will do the first step and will assuming they are logged out, they will not perform 2nd and 3rd step.

Personally, I feel that step C should be eleminated and user should be warned he might be logged into openid provider.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather _both_ B and C were eliminated. When you log out of, say, Facebook, it doesn't keep you logged in to "Facebook OpenID" (I assume; I haven't actually used FB as an OpenID provider). Stack Exchange shouldn't do so either. But I know [that's been asked before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118247/stack-exchange-openid-credentials-not-removed-on-logout-allowing-insecure-re-lo), and eliminating step C is certainly a more immediately important issue.

Comment: Any comment on this?

Comment: @SantaClaus any comment on what? On the question? You got upvotes, it means at least 7 users agree with you. As for official response from a team member be patient, they can't possibly answer each and every question here so quickly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, by comment I was talking about some official response from team. Anyway, I'll wait. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I would certainly upvote this question if I had enough rep on meta to do so.  The process for logging out of StackExchange with StackExchange OpenID is confusing.  I had to research it for 30 minutes to completely understand the problem.  When I log on to anything using my SE OpenID on a shared computer, I am still paranoid that the next user can sit down and log back in with a single click and no password.  I shouldn't have to manually clear cookies to keep this from happening.