# How does Stack Exchange's authorization works

Tags: discussion, authentication, cookies, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work)

After logging with an 3rd party account (facebook, google, ...), how does Stack Exchange Network save credentials?

I signed up through an existing facebook account, I tried deleting cookies and cache for stackoverflow.com and refreshed the page to see if still logged in, and indeed I am still logged in.

- If not by cookies, how are the credentials saved (where)?
- What information is saved in the browser?
- No matter if OpenId or Oauth(1 or 2) is used, what information is saved in the database when retrieving the information through those protocols?

Comment: oh, I see... thank you @Arjan ... I guess the answer is up to date, right?

Comment: No, the duplicate is not necessarily up to date. But that is how Stack Exchange sites work: to be a library of good questions and answers, we don't want the same thing to be asked multiple times.

Comment: Thank you @Arjan, but in the authorization process no database (MySQL, PostgreeSQL ...) at all? All the information is saved in the client's browser?

Comment: If you're thinking about those databases, then [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) is a must read.

Comment: wow, thank you for sharing those links

Answer (score 1):

It saves them using 2 storage methods: cookies and localStorage (html5), and *this is probably what you forgot to delete*. Without forgetting some kind of `Switching Protocol (ws://sockets)`

Also, seems that it's been reinforced, by storing it's own credentials on *stackauth.com* and on every associated network.

---

> - If not by cookies, how are the credentials saved (where)?

localStorage (html5)

> - What information is saved in the browser?

some kind of cryptic identifier of you (for SSO)

> - No matter if OpenId or Oauth(1 or 2) is used, what information is saved in the database when retrieving the information through those protocols?

using oauth, anything that you previously have *granted*.

That's the main motivation of the **oauth protocol**: you (as user) only have to enter your credentials only once to a protected authorization provider, and then, to have the right of grant (or not) to a third-party app a limited access of your personal information, to finally obtain an access_token; without sharing your credentials over the network again.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge Antonio (gracias xD), what about crossbrowser solutions? because there are people with older browsers, that don't support html5, which log ins the same way

Comment: thanks, i'm so glad. Crossbrowser solutions? is another very good question.. Nowadays, you have to implement several ways to store (and fetch) them locally (cookies, localStorage, localDatabase, SharedObject). The application must use one and if it fails, fall back to another. Kind of tricky. For javascript you can take a look at: http://www.jstorage.info/. o_O

Comment: oh, I see... than it seams that I will have to do some more researching before uploading the new app version with the oauth feature