# Why does the login not work across sites?

Tags: support, bug, login

When I login to one page, why do I need to enter my password for every other SE site I visit?
This used to work pretty well, but now it does not at all.

I just visited superuser, was logged out (once again) and needed to enter my credentials. I did that on stackexchange.com to be logged in back to all my accounts.
Then I got redirected to superuser and was not logged in.

Comment: Do you have a browser that doesn't like thrid-party cookies or a plugin that protects you from those third-party cookies? See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other

Comment: Nope. Everything stock.

Comment: Which browser do you use and on which OS are you?

Comment: Safari on OS X. I'm pretty sure it used work previously

Comment: It works with all sites that have StackExchange.com URLs. Super User doesn't. Safari blocks third party cookies by default.

Comment: See specifically what is mentioned in *stage 3* in [Global auth is dead! Long live universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260153/158100)