# How does identity follow me from site to site with Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, reputation, login

I've been a member of Stack Overflow for years and I also read other sites like https://security.stackexchange.com. This morning while I was logged into https://stackoverflow.com, I then went to security.StackExchange.com. There, it said I was not logged in and prompted me to create an account. I then tried logging in with my Stack Overflow data but it said not valid or something to that effect. Apparently these sites are linked but do not seem to honor each other's login. So I posted a question as a guest.

Later I desired to post a comment or even vote up the excellent answer I received to my guest question. But I could not. So in frustration I clicked create new account and gave it my exact same email, username and password that I use on Stack Overflow. It said nothing about any existing account but rather welcomed me to the new account.

So I presume even though these sites are all linked they still have separate logins and the reputation points etc do not apply to other linked sites. Is that correct?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260153/

Comment: *they still have separate logins*, you have a userprofile on each site which gets linked to your networkwide account when you join a site (assuming you are already logged in). *the reputation points etc do not apply to other linked sites. Is that correct?* Yes, that is correct although there does exist an so called association bonus, giving you +100 on all sites when you reach 200 reputation on one site.

Comment: This morning I noticed (before logging in) upon coming to http://meta.stackexchange.com, my user profile Icon was in place showing my notifications just as the links you gave eluded to. I still had to log in to do much but I'm beginning to see how things work here. Anyhow thanks for the comments I'm learning as I go. (edit because of accidental hit of enter key before finish.