# Does SO's still use localStorage to auto-login users?

Tags: support, login, openid, auto-login, session

I was searching about how SO authenticate and manage users sessions across multiple sites/domain and found this question from 2010:

[How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work?newreg=0f6f2a2291524574ad6fbc5b3bae0754)

However, I didn't found anything about it in 2020. Does it still use `localStorage` and StackAuth `iFrame` to share login tokens in the actual days?

Comment: No, it is using universal auth now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It uses cookies and cleverly posted XHR requests: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956/158100