# Is it possible to sign in to all Stack Exchange sites without cookies?

Tags: support, login, cookies

Can I avoid being prompted to sign in to every single Stack Exchange site, and having to type and save passwords multiply in the browser? The same login/password seems to work. Is there a Stack Exchange-wide login option, other then Google and Facebook? I've seen an official-looking page about global auto-login, but obviously it's not happening (using Firefox).

I do have Firefox / Privacy & Security / Enhanced Tracking Protection / Strict, which warns about "Cross-site tracking cookies". I also delete cookies on every browser exit. Most of the time, when I try to Ask, I'm being prompted to login (in the same session, for every site). But not every time.

Comment: It looks like the Help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials is incorrect: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/282094

Comment: You should be able to login once: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login but if you don't allow 3rd party cookies or use Safari then you're out of luck. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956/158100

Comment: Should already be possible. I log-in once for all my 170-ish accounts, wouldn't want to think about having those as separate logins.

Comment: @Rob as far as I can see that's not what it is about. OP wants to skip the "Join this community" step, and have account automatically on all sites. If I'm wrong, you're correct and help center should be fixed, but we need a separate request for that so the tag will still not fit here.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard That's not a sign-in though, that's a once-only question.

Comment: Ald, just to clarify:  Are you talking about the "Join community" login or the regular login?

Comment: Autojoin mostly, but actually I'm having problems with autologin intermittently. I do have Firefox / Privacy & Security / Enhanced Tracking Protection / Strict, which warns about "Cross-site tracking cookies". I also delete cookies on every browser exit. Most of the time, when I try to Ask, I'm being prompted to login (in the same session, for every site). But not every time.

Comment: @AldIn - Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment attempting to clarify your question.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard, I can only read what it says; and guess about what is unclear. --- You suggest: "... have account automatically on all sites.", you think they (and all users) want over 175 accounts; even on sites of languages they don't speak - well, that's quite a guess. --- OP says: "... avoid being prompted to sign in ..." (not "register"), and:  "... Stack Exchange-wide login option, other then Google and Facebook? I've seen an official-looking page about global auto-login ..." - so let's think they want an account on every site, everywhere. -- **+**, the "Help" is missing your idea.

Comment: @Rob well OP replied, I was wrong.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard, the term "autojoin" leads cause to wonder if it's more complicated than that; but 'presence across all sites' (log-in once, logged in throughout the network without having to register individually) I thinks is a dupe. --- Will someone be rolling back Ollie's edit, and restoring the tag I added?

Comment: @Rob well, the question is simple now that I understand it. OP doesn't want to type username and password more than once. This is working, I didn't type name and password for ages, however it's working only because I let the cookies live. Remove the cookies or block them, and you lose this nice feature.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard `Remove the cookies or block them, and you lose this nice feature.` - That's not true, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR0iJ.jpg

Comment: @Rob so you know how to enable those you need, but obviously OP doesn't know, hence they need to type name and password every time. (And asking how to enable specific cookies is off topic here, I guess)

Comment: No, they are all blocked.

Comment: @Rob well, I'm far from being expert in this field so can't know for sure. I do see the facts though: 1) OP is required to type name and password every time, and 2) OP is blocking cookies, so I made 1+1. If you have contradicting information, feel free to post answer so OP can at least confirm it.

Comment: @Sha, with [their most recent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356470/is-it-possible-to-sign-in-to-all-stack-exchange-sites-without-cookies?noredirect=1#comment1191219_356479) I believe that they've figured it out. They need to login once (after logging out) to be logged in to all the sites that they have joined (not 'everywhere', *onlythere*).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to keep you signed in without prompting for name and password, a site **must** use cookies.

You [said yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356470/sign-in-to-all-stack-exchange-sites?noredirect=1#comment1191134_356470):

> I also delete cookies on every browser exit

And:

> I do have Firefox / Privacy & Security / Enhanced Tracking Protection / Strict

So it means you delete and disable the cookies required to keep you logged in.

That is the reason you can't avoid being prompted for name and password.

Comment: In other words, you got precisely what you asked for!

Comment: Clearing cookies on exit only means I have to log in at least once every time I open the browser. It's cross-site cookies that make a difference. With all the cookies and offline storage being shoved down our browsers these days (and, adding insult to injury, the forced-consent brought about by privacy regulations), clear-on-exit seems to me the only reasonable option.

Comment: @usretc is absolutely right, cookie clearing on exit doesn't have anything to do with SSO during a given session.