# Why do I have to re-log in on all *.SE sites, one after another?

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

I usually log in on https://stackoverflow.com, after I do a full browser reset or cookie cleaning.

After this, I noticed I am *not* automatically logged in on https://stackexchange.com. So I usually log in a second time on https://stackexchange.com.

But then, for other sites:

- meta.SE
- SuperUser
- AskUbuntu
- ServerFault
- etc.

I have to re-log-in on each of them!

There is no option like "Log in with your already-logged-in SE account":

[image]

As far as I remember, in the past, I used to log in on SO *only*, and then I was automatically in on the other websites.

**How to enable this again?**

It's very unconvenient to have to enter the username/password for every website.

---

Note : third party cookies are disabled in my browser Chrome. But I whitelisted these:

[image]

and the problem is still there.

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Do you allow third party cookies in your browser? If not, allow/whitelist the SE domains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to sign in to all Stack Exchange sites without cookies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356470/is-it-possible-to-sign-in-to-all-stack-exchange-sites-without-cookies)

Comment: @Luuklag No, I don't delete cookies on every browser exit. It's a different issue.

Comment: @rene True, I disallowed third party cookies in Chrome! That might be the reason. How to whitelist them? Should I whitelist also all domain specific websites: superuser.com, serverfault.com, etc. If so, would be interesting to have a detailed answer.

Comment: @rene I tried with "block third party cookies" still enabled, but whitelist (including 3rd party cookies) for stackexchange.com, serverfault.com. But still when arriving on serverfault.com I am logged out...

Comment: Did you re-authenticate once?

Comment: @rene Please look at the edited question, I added a screenshot at the end.

Comment: Also see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208

Comment: @rene Yes, I just did. I cleaned all cookies, and re-authentificated once again on SE.com Then going on serverfault.com shows the same problem.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Based on the details in my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956/158100 I would expect that now to work.

Comment: Can you also whitelist `[*.]stackauth.com`?

Comment: If you clean cookies and then re-authenticate please use stackoverflow.com and then visit serverfault.com. StackExchange.com is a bit weird and might not cooperate as you would expect.

Comment: I retried all of this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgtB0.png (see edited question), but it still fails. Should `[*.]` be included in the pattern?

Comment: @Basj Hmm, maybe that pattern is not correct in hindsight. If you open a dev console, can you see the calls being made to the other domains and are there cookies returned in their response headers?

Comment: Hi @Basj, were you able to solve this issue in the past years ?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to allow **all** cross-site cookies and third-party cookies. I have also tried setting the tracking prevention (in Edge/Firefox/Chrome) to balanced and disabled any blocking extensions. It should work after a browser reload (that is, closing the browser and then opening it again with the same windows.)