# Social Distancing (Main) earned on too many sites

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash-2020

I just [earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha#winter-bash) Social Distancing (Main) on Server Fault, Super User, Ask Ubuntu, and StackApps, but I didn't visit those sites.

For what it's worth I just logged in, which (if I recall correctly) cycles me through all the own-domain sites to set the login cookie; I assume that's the reason? That's not visiting a question page though.

Comment: *If I recall correctly* ... I think you perfectly recalls how it works ...

Comment: @rene It's been more than 1.5 years, who knows what changed 

Comment: Trust me, I've fantasized about that blackbox over the last years more then enough to confirm [my guess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other/312956#312956) is still accurate, and so is yours.

Comment: So did you actually earn them, or were they just awarded to you? ;)

Comment: To be fair, one could argue that it's even *more* distant if you only access the site through an AJAX ping during authentication.

Comment: @AdamLear "Sorry StackApps, but I just hung out with SO and MSE, and I really want to reduce my contacts right now. Maybe next year?"

Comment: Your Flashlight hat might (I don't know) be harder to explain. I have mine for pt.SO (after setting the Dark Mode on SO) while you have yours on all the available SO sites (four of them) - did you set Dark Mode on each site ? --- Answer: Some things don't work without you.

Comment: @Rob No, I enabled dark mode on SO proper, waited for the hat, and disabled it again. Never visited the non-English sites. I think there's already a separate bug for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the hat is awarded based on the presence of `DailySiteAccess` records for a `User` in their `UserHistory`. Apparently, this user history entry is given more generously than I anticipated. But it is what it is (I am not going to audit this or change the trigger criteria for the hat at this point). Enjoy the extra hats.

Comment: If that's so, then there's a [handy existing user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/7173/stack-exchange-global-flag-summary) that will trigger the hat award on all sites. Useful if you're tired of being continuously notified of the hat when you're browsing multiple sites (e.g. through HNQ).

Comment: Fair enough. I seem to remember a separate history entry for page views, but I'm not sure. Either way, probably not worth worrying about. Thanks for your work!