# Is there a way to create a "general" login for all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: bug, login

On Stack Overflow, I'm user `user:4279155`. Imagine I login on that site, then:

- I surf to [the *Software Engineering* site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).
- I surf to [the *Super User* site](https://superuser.com/).

This gives different behaviour for Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome web browsers:

For both web browsers, I get logged in immediately at [the *Software Engineering* site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).
At [the *Super User* site](https://superuser.com/) however:

- using Microsoft Edge, I get logged in automatically.
- using Google Chrome, I don't get logged in automatically.

Is this a bug of the Stack Exchange site? (I'm a regular user of Google Chrome and I would like to get logged in at every Stack Exchange site I visit.)

Before I forget, I have the habit of [surfing incognito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_browsing) (also known as InPrivate).

Comment: Inprivate blocks third party cookies and that is needed for SSO to work in the SE network. Read here what happens under the hood: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other/312956#312956

Comment: But then how can it work for one browser and not for another?

Comment: Because chrome and edge use different security settings as default. Blame edge for not caring about your privacy.