# Can't login to Area 51 on Safari

Tags: bug, area-51, login, safari

When trying to login to Area 51 on Safari (15.2, macOS Monterey 12.1), it asks me to login on Meta Stack Exchange (which is expected) but the browser gets stuck on a redirect page:

[image]

In the browser console, I see a lot of CORS errors:

```
[Error] Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Cannot load image https://serverfault.com/users/login/universal.gif?authToken=[authToken]&nonce=[nonce] due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (universal.gif, line 0)
[Error] Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Cannot load image https://superuser.com/users/login/universal.gif?authToken=[authToken]&nonce=[nonce] due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (universal.gif, line 0)
[Error] Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Cannot load image https://stackoverflow.com/users/login/universal.gif?authToken=[authToken]&nonce=[nonce] due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (universal.gif, line 0)
[Error] Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Cannot load image https://stackapps.com/users/login/universal.gif?authToken=[authToken]&nonce=[nonce] due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (universal.gif, line 0)
[Error] Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Cannot load image https://askubuntu.com/users/login/universal.gif?authToken=[authToken]&nonce=[nonce] due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (universal.gif, line 0)
[Error] Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Cannot load image https://mathoverflow.net/users/login/universal.gif?authToken=[authToken]&nonce=[nonce] due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://meta.stackexchange.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (universal.gif, line 0)
```

(authentication tokens and nonces have been stripped out of the console log)

I've cleared the cache for relevant websites but to no avail. It happens in private mode as well.

Comment: You know the stuff about the `universal.gif`?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy actually, I don't... if it's relevant to the question, please enlighten me :)

Comment: I am glad to! So to perform the authentication across different domains, Stack Exchange uses a mechanism (that uses the *authentication tokens and nonces* you talked about, that mechanism is explained by *rene* here :https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other/312956#312956. So that image is getting loaded and creating this whole bug. I don't understand this whole thing, but that should help you to notify the developers about where is the problem.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy thank you! I've tried disabling the option to prevent cross-site tracking but that didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the "thank you!" compliment. Yes it isn't cross-site cookies or fingerprinting or some sort but a clever engineering. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a parameter present in HTTP queries, I don't know more, but [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) will do fine. By the way *rene* is terrifically talented you know?