# How can I log in into Stack Overflow NOT using a Google account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid, google-openid

I was very furious that by clicking on "log in", Stack Overflow gives only two options: *create* a Google account or get the hell out of here. I *have* an account here and I want to log in to *it*, not creating Google one. How do I do it?!

[image]

The only way I found (might be useful to someone):
Open the incognito window, log in to Stack Overflow – since the Google token¹ is not saved in incognito, Stack Overflow  will not offer to log in using Google, there will be a standard login page. You need to log in to the site in a way convenient for you, click on the profile, settings (slightly below the avatar), My login, add more logins... add a Google account (you will need to log in to it) – now, in normal mode, Stack Overflow will not ask stupid questions and also logins in automatically as you refresh the page.

But after all, I think Stack Overflow creators should do something with this inconvenient logging in and having to link Google account in order to login into Stack Overflow conveniently when you have Google account token¹ in your browser. Why not use the standard login page regardless is user has Google token¹ or not? The user shouldn't go through all this hell, so I tagged it as a bug because regardless is it a bug, it should be fixed.

¹ not sure how correctly to name it. I mean that you had logged in into a Google account somewhen and it's now saved for all sites. Probably I used the wrong terminology for that.

Comment: uhh, you can do a standard username and password login

Comment: @JourneymanGeek still need email, and OP most likely used their gmail.

Comment: Sorry, but as a bug report, this post needs some more details. What exactly happened when you tried to log in when in your main session and not a private session? Can you please take a screenshot of that page and put it here? It'd be nice if we had clear instructions on how to reproduce your issue; currently, I don't understand what you're reporting since I *do* get the option to log in with a different provider.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog When I click the blue button in the top of the page, I go to the https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=head where I have only 2 options: to create account or cancel. If I click "cancel", I will be returned to the main page. Attached the screenshot to the topic

Comment: Ah, your question is answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login): essentially, the system still recognizes you're logged into the overall SE network when you browse a site on which you don't have a profile, and instead of giving you an explicit login option, since you're already logged into the network, it offers to create a profile on that site and link it to the account you're already logged into. See *What this means right now* in that post.

Comment: I think you are misreading the message, it is **not**: " ***create*** a Google account ...", it is: "use your (already existing) GMail address and associated password to identify yourself ". Logging in from the same email address (and password) **avoids** creating multiple accounts, logging in with different email addresses **allows** multiple accounts (which you may not want).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one Stack Exchange site know that I'm logged in to the other?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other) - and [the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) in [Sonic's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377851/how-can-i-log-in-into-stack-overflow-not-using-a-google-account#comment1261126_377851).

Comment: @Rob basically, SonictheSaveUkraine-hog answered my question. 
Since I didn't know I have loggined into another SE site. The problem is that I haven't a Google-associated account in Stack Overflow, but in the same time I wasn't able to login in another account. In other words, the problem was I can't access the standard login page with email-password login, so the answer should describe how in my situation can I go to a standard login page, bypassing the Google one you can see in the screenshot. One of the answers I have posted myself in this post.

Comment: @Rob The answer you send answers on "how does it happens", not "how to solve it"

Comment: So, the solution probably is to log out from all SE sites, but I don't know which site I was logined in with a Google. Even deleting the account (while loggined with Google) doesn't remove the prompt in the screenshot when I try to login again (Now when I attached Google account to my account, it doesn't happens even if I disattach google account again).

Comment: And now, realizing what kind of situation it was, I still think the best solution for SE devs would be creating "login with other account" button in this prompt, or letting user other way to go to the standard login page (in similar situation)

Comment: You don't create a new Google account. You just create a new account **on the site where you sign up in**. With your own existing account. It is clear, for me at least, from the text, but if you have idea how to word it better, you can start new feature request asking SE to change the wording.

Comment: I just shortended "create new SE account using Google" to "create a Google account". Sorry for my English, I didn't notice that it has a completely different meaning. I had to say "to create account with Google". Should I edit the question with this correction?

Anyway, the main problem is not about I wasn't understand what happened, but about had no possibility to login, only to create a new SE account using Google account

Comment: I suggested that this was a duplicate, but everyone else closed this question as "needs details or clarity". --- You should read through your comments, particularly [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377851/how-can-i-log-in-into-stack-overflow-not-using-a-google-account#comment1261198_377851) and **edit your question** to add all the necessary details, instead of leaving them in comments. That will queue your question for reopening and allow more people to provide an answer. --- You may also choose to leave it closed, or delay reopening.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use 'someone elses' SSO to log in - I'm currently using a username/password based login, with a <username>+text@gmail.com email. There's no need to use their login

Basically ignore the 2 buttons on top, and fill in a username, password and your email and it should just work. I just tested this, and it works perfectly fine

[image]

Comment: The author just edited their question right before you answered with a screenshot - they're not seeing a login prompt, but a "join this community" prompt, which is shown when a user is logged in on another site and doesn't have a profile on the site they're trying to sign into. The prompt they're seeing is to join the site and link it with their network account.

Comment: Or right after, from my perspective!

Comment: Timestamps don't lie - your answer was posted three minutes after their edit.

Comment: It wasn't there when I started?

Comment: The author didn't violate any rules against invalidating existing answers, because this didn't exist at the time they made the edit and they had no way of knowing this answer was going to get posted. And this answer is unhelpful in solving the author's problem, because they're seeing a completely different prompt from the one you depict.